# How to add UIView to custom UITableViewCell in drawRect method

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, drawinrect

In my project need to add uiview in UITableViewCell. I can add UIView using following code in UITableViewCell class.

```
    -(void)drawRect{
       [cell.contentView addSubview:myView];
    }
```

Is this a efficient way to show when large amount of table cell are displaying. Is there other way to add UIView using method like.

```
    drawInRect
```

Comment: this question is vague at best so don't expect a straight answer. If you just want to `-addSubview:` then I **don't** believe this is the right place for it.

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is the best place to do so, not `drawRect`. However, if this subview of yours will be added in a lot of cells, why not make it a property of your subclassed cell, and toggle `hidden`/`frame` when you need to show/hide it?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add the subView in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` which is part of `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use drawRect method that way. That method is using for drawing some parts of the ui-element and may call several times per a sec.
You should add a subview in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method (`UITableViewDataSource` protocol) or in `- (void)awakeFromNib`. 
Don't forget to remove that subview in `- (void)prepareForReuse` method of your UITableViewCell subclass.